# tf.keras replace lower layer in pretrained resnet50

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is it possible to remove/replace the BOTTOM layers of a pretrained ResNet50 model in tf.keras.applications?

For instance, I've tried doing this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
pretrained_resnet = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256,256,1))
x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,
                           kernel_size=(7,7),
                           strides=(2,2),
                           padding='same')(x)
outputs = pretrained_resnet.layers[3](x)
test = tf.keras.Model(inputs, pretrained_resnet.output)
```

But it gives this error: ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", .......

I've also tried using the tf.keras Sequential API, but that doesn't work since ResNet isn't a sequential model. I'm basically just trying to replace the first Conv2D layer in ResNet50 with a new one. Is this possible? Or do I have to rewrite the entire ResNet model?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ZeroPadding2D` and `Conv2D (7*7, 64, stride 2)` are the `2nd` and `3rd` layers of `Resnet50` network. Can you please confirm, are you looking to replace only first layer i.e input layer ? If yes, in the answer section, I have provided the solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZeroPadding2D` and `Conv2D (7*7, 64, stride 2)` are the `2nd` and `3rd` layers of `Resnet50` network.

Hence, showing here to replace only first layer (i.e input layer) in `Resnet50`

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
import tensorflow as tf

model = ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
model.save('model.h5')

res50_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
#res50_model.summary()
```

To remove first layer from network, you can run code as below

```
 res50_model._layers.pop(0)
```

`Resnet50 expects the input must have 3 channels`, hence adding input layer shape as `(256,256,3)` instead of `(256,256,1)`.

To add new input layer, you can run code as below

```
newInput = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256,256,3))
newOutputs = res50_model(newInput)
newModel = tf.keras.Model(newInput, newOutputs)
newModel.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Model)             multiple                  23587712  
=================================================================
Total params: 23,587,712
Trainable params: 23,534,592
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: May I ask why you save and load model before replacing the layer ?